# Zookeeper connection failing cp-rest-proxy with spotify kafka image

Tags: java, docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, kafka-rest

I have been using the kafka image provided by spotify to run kafka locally. I'm currently trying to use it with `cp-kafka-rest` and `schema-registry` images.

I need help resolving this issue:

**ERROR (Log Group: `kafka_rest_1_609fd108dcf4`)**

[main-SendThread(zookeeper:2181)] WARN org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Session 0x0 for server zookeeper:2181, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect

```
java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException 
  at sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Net.java:101)
  at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:622)
  at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.registerAndConnect(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:277)
  at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.connect(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:287)
  at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.startConnect(ClientCnxn.java:1021)
  at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1064)
```

**Docker Compose**

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  kafka:
    image: 'spotify/kafka'
    hostname: kafka
    environment:
      - ADVERTISED_HOST=kafka
      - ADVERTISED_PORT=9092
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "2181:2181"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - one
  kafka_rest:
    image: 'confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest:5.1.0'
    hostname: kafka_rest
    environment:
      - KAFKA_REST_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - KAFKA_REST_LISTENERS=http://0.0.0.0:8082
      - KAFKA_REST_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL=http:schema-registry:8081
      - KAFKA_REST_HOST_NAME=kafka-rest
    networks:
      - one
  schema_registry:
    hostname: schema-registry
    image: 'confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:5.1.0'
    environment:
      - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL=zookeeper:2181
      - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME=schema-registry
      - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS=http://0.0.0.0:8081
    networks:
      - one
networks:
  one:
    name: rest_network
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have no `zookepeer` container - it is actually your "`kafka`" service image that includes both Zookeeper and Kafka servers, so `zookeeper:2181` should rather be `kafka:2181`

---

**However**, I would recommend not using the spotify images, as they are significantly outdated

You can find a fully functional Docker Compose example of the [entire Confluent 5.1.0 Platform on Github](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images/blob/5.1.0-post/examples/cp-all-in-one/docker-compose.yml)

Here is the revelvant configuration you are looking for

```
---
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.1.0
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka:5.1.0
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "29092:29092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092
      KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:9092
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'true'
      CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous'

  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:5.1.0
    hostname: schema-registry
    container_name: schema-registry
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - broker
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL: 'zookeeper:2181'

  rest-proxy:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest:5.1.0
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - broker
      - schema-registry
    ports:
      - 8082:8082
    hostname: rest-proxy
    container_name: rest-proxy
    environment:
      KAFKA_REST_HOST_NAME: rest-proxy
      KAFKA_REST_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:9092'
      KAFKA_REST_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8082"
      KAFKA_REST_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema-registry:8081'
```

Comment: I get an error that says `Error connecting to node broker:9092 (id: 1 rack: null) (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
java.io.IOException: Can't resolve address: broker:9092` when I create a console producer. It worked after I added `broker` to `/etc/hosts`  as `localhost`

Comment: The rest proxy shouldn't be giving that error... Please don't edit your hosts file! That is just a hack. From outside of the Docker network, you need to use `localhost:29092`. Read https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/

Answer (score -2):

You need to add zookeeper service to your docker compose file

```
zookeeper:
image: confluent/zookeeper
ports:
  - "2181:2181"
environment:
  zk_id: "1"
network_mode: "host"
```

Comment: The spotify/kafka container includes Zookeeper